# What is the range of pointer memory in C

Tags: c, pointers

How many values/spaces can be allocated in a pointers. Is there a way to find the total number of allocations possible.

Comment: In principle, the difference between, say, two `char` pointers in the object representation of an object must be representable by `ptrdiff_t`, so that gives you an upper bound. But that's probably not a realistic bound on modern systems.

Comment: Are you asking how much memory a single variable can hold? Or how much memory is available in general?

Comment: Yes As it is dependent on the configuration. Is there any way to compute that.

Comment: @KerrekSB Producing a `ptrdiff_t` between two objects that aren't in the same array is an example of undefined behaviour.

Comment: From the C language perspective this is unspecified.

Comment: @Seb: Sure. But you could imagine setting up a single, static array of chars for your application and performing all memory management yourself. But indeed, separate small allocations could sum to a much larger size than a single allocation; e.g. allocations probably cannot cross segment boundaries.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, only the `NULL` value ("zero", but not necessarily all zero bits) is reserved in C, so the rest of the pointer-type's number space values are all valid pointer addresses as far as the C language is concerned, but on a particular platform then many additional rules apply which will reduce the available memory space (such as memory-mapped IO, for example).

(Note that I assume you're talking about a flat memory space, like we have with true 32-bit programming, and not like the days of 16-bit programming where you have `near` and `far` pointers and all kinds of memory hacks).

Expanding on my "particular platform" note, on 32-bit Windows [the user-process address space is 2 GiB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778.aspx#memory_limits) (`0x000000` to `0x7FFFFFFF`) instead of 4GiB because the upper bit of a 32-bit pointer in Windows is reserved (unless you specify the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag).

As for the total number of allocations: (e.g. how many times can you allocate a single byte buffer) then that depends on the implementation of the allocator - and the parent OS, because there is a space overhead for each allocation (there are many different ways of implementing an alocator, with different structures and algorithms) so I can't make a general statement.

Comment: Other particulars to note are padding and alignment requirements for any non-character types (and even some of the character types).